# locked out of server manager in Windows server

Tags: windows, server

I was working on group policies on windows server using virtual box. I was trying to block the access of some applications for the user which was created in that group policy. But some how I messed up something now I am locked out of my server manager too. it says blocked by system manager. Even though I am logged in as admin in the windows server. Every application has been saying that when I am trying to open it. Even the command prompt. Please help thankyou. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWrdN.png)

Was working on group policies.